# BQ: Select latest date from multiple columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Good day, all. I wrote a question relating to this earlier, but now I have encountered another problem.

I have to calculate the **timestamp** difference between the install_time and contributer_time columns. HOWEVER, I have three contributor_time columns, and I need to select the latest time from those columns first then subtract it from install time.

Sample Data

| users | install_time | contributor_time_1 | contributor_time_2 | contributor_time_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8:00 | 7:45 | 7:50 | 7:55 |
| 2 | 10:00 | 9:15 | 9:45 | 9:30 |
| 3 | 11:00 | 10:30 | null | null |

For example, in the table above I would need to select contributor_time_3 and subtract it from install_time for user 1. For user 2, I would do the same, but with contributor_time_2.

Sample Results

| users | install_time | time_diff_min |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8:00 | 5 |
| 2 | 10:00 | 15 |
| 3 | 11:00 | 30 |

The problem I am facing is that 1) the contributor_time columns are in string format and 2) some of them have 'null' string values (which means that I cannot cast it into a timestamp.)

I created a query, but I am am facing an error stating that I cannot subtract a string from timestamp. So I added safe_cast, however the time_diff_min results are only showing when I have all three contributor_time columns as a timestamp. For example, in the sample table above, only the first two rows will pull.

The query I have so far is below:

```
SELECT
  users,
  install_time,
  TIMESTAMP_DIFF(install_time, greatest(contributor_time_1, contributor_time_2, contributor_time_3), MINUTE) as ctct_min 
FROM
  (SELECT 
  users,
  install_time,
  safe_cast(contributor_time_1 as timestamp) as contributor_time_1,
  safe_cast(contributor_time_2 as timestamp) as contributor_time_2,
  safe_cast(contributor_time_3 as timestamp) as contributor_time_3,
  FROM 
  (SELECT 
  users,
  install_time,
  case when contributor_time_1 = 'null' then '0' else contributor_time_1 end as contributor_time_1,
  ....
  FROM datasource
```

Any help to point me in the right direction is appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Consider below

```
select users, install_time,
  time_diff(
    parse_time('%H:%M',install_time), 
    greatest(
      parse_time('%H:%M',contributor_time_1), 
      parse_time('%H:%M',contributor_time_2),
      parse_time('%H:%M',contributor_time_3)
    ), 
    minute) as time_diff_min
from `project.dataset.table`
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Above can be refactored slightly into below

```
create temp function latest_time(arr any type) as ((
  select parse_time('%H:%M',val) time
  from unnest(arr) val
  order by time desc
  limit 1 
));
select users, install_time,
  time_diff(
    parse_time('%H:%M',install_time), 
    latest_time([contributor_time_1, contributor_time_2, contributor_time_3]), 
    minute) as time_diff_min
from `project.dataset.table`
```

less verbose and no redundant parsing - with same result - so just matter of preferences

Comment: Hi Mikhail, I do apologize. I am still getting used to Stack Overflow. I will take this into account for future references. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: second / refactored version in above answer actually covers your null scenario!!!!

Comment: Hello Mikhail. Thank you for your response. I attempted the refactored version and still received this error message: Failed to parse input string "null".

Comment: `null` and string `null` are totally different things. I've got impression you have null's in your table not strings - still it is easy to fix / adjust above for this - just use `safe.parse_time` instead of `parse_time`

Comment: Hello Mikhail. Unfortunately, when I used safe.parse_time, I am still not getting all of the results for time_diff_min, only the results which have the three contributor_time columns with the actual timestamps (i.e. time_diff_min is not calculated for any rows with any 'null' in the time columns).  I looked around a bit more... I read that the val function stops reading the string once it encounters a non-numeric number... in this case, it would be 'null'. Is this correct?

Comment: Hello Mikhail. I was able to solve my problem. I used greatest(cast(replace(contributor_time_1,'null', "2020-01-01 06:00:00 UTC") AS TIMESTAMP)) to first replace the null string with a default timestamp, cast that string as a timestamp, and lastly obtain the greatest value. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: as I mentioned already - second solution in my answer does work with 'null's, so I don't know what kind of problem you are experiencing. the only I can think of  is  - you don't properly adjusted all instances of parse_time with safe as a prefix

Answer (score 1):

You can use `greatest()`:

```
select t.*,
       time_diff(install_time, greatest(contributor_time_1, contributor_time_2, contributor_time_3), minute) as diff_min
from t;
```

Note: this assumes that the values are never `NULL`, which seems reasonable based on your sample data.

Comment: Hi Gordon. Thank you for your response. I received this error: 

No matching signature for function TIMESTAMP_DIFF for argument types: TIMESTAMP, STRING, DATE_TIME_PART. Supported signature: TIMESTAMP_DIFF(TIMESTAMP, TIMESTAMP, DATE_TIME_PART)

It looks like the contributed_time columns are in a string format and need to be cast first. I put that cast() in my query, but I am still receiving the same error. Do you have an idea as to why? Thank you for your expertise!

Comment: (1) Your question and this answer are about *times* not timestamps.  (2) If you are storing the values as strings, you need to convert them to the appropriate format.

Comment: Thank you Gordon. I should have provided more detail in the sample table. In fact, I didn't realize there were null values until I checked. Good to know that greatest() doesn't work with them.

Comment: Hi Gordon. Thank you for your help. I had to do a little bit of manoeuvring, but I was able to deal with the null strings. I used greatest(cast(replace(contributor_time_1,'null', "2020-01-01 06:00:00 UTC") AS TIMESTAMP)) and my results were fine. Thank you for your help.